# android 10 detect if "background location services" are disabled by power saving mode

Tags: android, background, gps, battery

I have given up on obtaining the power saving mode for Android 10 as isPowerSaveMode() does not appear to work any more.
Instead I can work with knowing if "background location services" are enabled.
This appears to be disabled when choosing a power saving mode of "Medium Power Saving".
However I cannot see anything in the documentation on how to detect it.

```
checkSelfPermission(thisContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
```

seems to be unaffected by this power saving setting.
Any help very gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You will still have this permission even if power saving is enabled. I don't think this approach will be able to give you the information you want.